# Slow Dynamic resource transfer in Jetty/HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, servlets, jetty

We have an environment where each user may get different html/js/css resources. I'm using the following code to compress and transfer a java script resource:

```
public static byte[] compress(String str) throws IOException {
        if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        ByteArrayOutputStream obj=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(obj);
        gzip.write(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        gzip.close();
        return obj.toByteArray();
}

...
HttpServletResponse raw = response.raw();
raw.setBufferSize(file.length().intValue());
ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = raw.getOutputStream();
servletOutputStream.write(compress(FileUtils.readFileToString(file)));
servletOutputStream.flush();
servletOutputStream.close();
...
```

Inspecting the problem using chrome network tab, the download time is 2 seconds for 300KB of compressed data - this seems unreasonable. 
The problem is not the bandwidth or jetty itself, because static resources transfer time is fast.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if that is the source of your bottleneck, but I wouldn't do:

```
 raw.setBufferSize(file.length().intValue());
```

If the gzipped file is around 300KB then you could create response buffers which are a magnitude greater than that. And you don't need a big response buffer at all when you are streaming static content.

From the servlet javadoc:

> Sets the preferred buffer size for the body of the response. The
>   servlet container will use a buffer at least as large as the size
>   requested. The actual buffer size used can be found using
>   getBufferSize.
>
> A larger buffer allows more content to be written before anything is
>   actually sent, thus providing the servlet with more time to set
>   appropriate status codes and headers. A smaller buffer decreases
>   server memory load and allows the client to start receiving data more
>   quickly.